# Chrome Extension. How to get html of a URL in a Content script Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the html of a URL in a Content script (javascript).

Normally I would use `XMLHttpRequest` but seems like I can't in Content script...
So. Does anybody knows a way to get the html of a URL in a Content Script?

BTW, the URL I want to get the html from is the Youtube search list api.

**EDIT:** This is what I have in the `popup.js` and working. but not working in the `ContentScript.js`:

```
function makeHttpObject() {
    try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
    catch (error) {}
    try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (error) {}
    try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (error) {}

    throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
var url = "https://www.google.com";
alert(url);
var html = "";
var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", url,false);
request.send(null);
html = request.responseText;
```

Comment: You need to do it in a background script because modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts. See the [official explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) for more details and examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your reply. But how can I do from the content script a function that will communicate with the background script, ask him to get the html and send it back? Aren't background script work only once?

Comment: Simply use messaging as shown in the document I've linked, also in the official [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation for extensions as well as [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).